Folium SideBySideLayers: Markers Not Displaying Correctly on Separate Layers
I’m trying to create a map using the Folium library in Python, where I want to use the SideBySideLayers plugin to compare two different tile layers. Each layer should have its own set of markers, but I’m facing an issue where the markers are visible on both layers, instead of being restricted to their respective layers.
import folium
from folium import plugins, FeatureGroup

# Create Map
m = folium.Map(location=(30, 20), zoom_start=4)

# Create layers
layer_left = folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron', name='Layer Left')
layer_right = folium.TileLayer('openstreetmap', name='Layer Right')

# Add layers to map
layer_left.add_to(m)
layer_right.add_to(m)

# Create SideBySideLayers
sbs = plugins.SideBySideLayers(layer_left=layer_left, layer_right=layer_right)
sbs.add_to(m)

fg_left = FeatureGroup(name='Markers left', show=True)
fg_right = FeatureGroup(name='Markers right', show=True)


fg_left.add_child(folium.Marker(location=(35, 25), popup='Left: Point A', icon=folium.Icon(color='blue')))
fg_left.add_child(folium.Marker(location=(34, 24), popup='Left: Point B', icon=folium.Icon(color='blue')))

fg_right.add_child(folium.Marker(location=(25, 15), popup='Right: Point C', icon=folium.Icon(color='red')))
fg_right.add_child(folium.Marker(location=(26, 16), popup='Right: Point D', icon=folium.Icon(color='red')))

fg_left.add_to(m) #or layer_left.add_child(fg_left)
fg_right.add_to(m) #or layer_right.add_child(fg_right)


m.save("split_map.html")


What i try to do :
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/swipe-1-loop-red.gif

Seems like it is not possible with Folium.
Folium use js script located at  https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/digidem/leaflet-side-by-side@2.0.0/leaflet-side-by-side.js and, related to this post : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/451897/imageoverlay-is-not-working-with-leaflet-side-by-side/452123#452123 we have to change the js for doing what i want.
Here is an exemple in html and js :
HTML :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.css"/>

    <style>html, body {width: 100%;height: 100%;}</style>
    <style>#map {position:absolute;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map" ></div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/leaflet@1.9.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="leaflet-side-by-side.js"></script> 
<script>
    
            var map = L.map(
                "map",
                {
                    center: [45.0, 20.0],
                    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857,
                    zoom: 4,
                    zoomControl: true,
                    preferCanvas: false,
                }
            );
    
            map.createPane('left');
            map.createPane('right');
            var leftmap = L.tileLayer( "https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png", {
                pane: 'left',
                maxZoom: 10
                }).addTo(map);

            var rightmap = L.tileLayer( "https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
                pane: 'right',
                maxZoom: 8
                }).addTo(map);
                
            var marker_1 = L.marker([45.5, 2], {
                pane: 'left'
                }).addTo(map);
                
            var marker_2 = L.marker([50.5, 4], {
                pane: 'left'
                }).addTo(map);
    
            var marker_3 = L.marker([48.5, 31], {
                pane: 'right'
                }).addTo(map);
            var sideBySideControl = L.control.sideBySide(leftmap, rightmap).addTo(map);


</script>

</script>
</body>  
</html>

JS :
(function(){function r(e,n,t){function o(i,f){if(!n[i]){if(!e[i]){var c="function"==typeof require&&require;if(!f&&c)return c(i,!0);if(u)return u(i,!0);var a=new Error("Cannot find module '"+i+"'");throw a.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",a}var p=n[i]={exports:{}};e[i][0].call(p.exports,function(r){var n=e[i][1][r];return o(n||r)},p,p.exports,r,e,n,t)}return n[i].exports}for(var u="function"==typeof require&&require,i=0;i<t.length;i++)o(t[i]);return o}return r})()({1:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (global){
var L = (typeof window !== "undefined" ? window['L'] : typeof global !== "undefined" ? global['L'] : null)
require('./layout.css')
require('./range.css')

var mapWasDragEnabled
var mapWasTapEnabled

// Leaflet v0.7 backwards compatibility
function on (el, types, fn, context) {
  types.split(' ').forEach(function (type) {
    L.DomEvent.on(el, type, fn, context)
  })
}

// Leaflet v0.7 backwards compatibility
function off (el, types, fn, context) {
  types.split(' ').forEach(function (type) {
    L.DomEvent.off(el, type, fn, context)
  })
}

function getRangeEvent (rangeInput) {
  return 'oninput' in rangeInput ? 'input' : 'change'
}

function cancelMapDrag () {
  mapWasDragEnabled = this._map.dragging.enabled()
  mapWasTapEnabled = this._map.tap && this._map.tap.enabled()
  this._map.dragging.disable()
  this._map.tap && this._map.tap.disable()
}

function uncancelMapDrag (e) {
  this._refocusOnMap(e)
  if (mapWasDragEnabled) {
    this._map.dragging.enable()
  }
  if (mapWasTapEnabled) {
    this._map.tap.enable()
  }
}

// convert arg to an array - returns empty array if arg is undefined
function asArray (arg) {
  return (arg === 'undefined') ? [] : Array.isArray(arg) ? arg : [arg]
}

function noop () {}

// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
function isTouch() {
  return (('ontouchstart' in window)
      || (navigator.MaxTouchPoints > 0)
      || (navigator.msMaxTouchPoints > 0));    
}
// end fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------

L.Control.SideBySide = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    thumbSize: 42,
    padding: 0
  },

  initialize: function (leftLayers, rightLayers, options) {
    this.setLeftLayers(leftLayers)
    this.setRightLayers(rightLayers)
    L.setOptions(this, options)
  },

  getPosition: function () {
    var rangeValue = this._range.value
    var offset = (0.5 - rangeValue) * (2 * this.options.padding + this.options.thumbSize)
    return this._map.getSize().x * rangeValue + offset
  },

  setPosition: noop,

  includes: L.Evented.prototype || L.Mixin.Events,

  addTo: function (map) {
    this.remove()
    this._map = map

    var container = this._container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-sbs', map._controlContainer)

    this._divider = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-sbs-divider', container)
    var range = this._range = L.DomUtil.create('input', 'leaflet-sbs-range', container)
    range.type = 'range'
    range.min = 0
    range.max = 1
    range.step = 'any'
    range.value = 0.5
    range.style.paddingLeft = range.style.paddingRight = this.options.padding + 'px'
    this._addEvents()
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  remove: function () {
    if (!this._map) {
      return this
    }
    if (this._leftLayer) {
// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
//      this._leftLayer.getContainer().style.clip = ''
      this._leftLayer.getPane().style.clip = ''
// end fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
    }
    if (this._rightLayer) {
// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
//      this._rightLayer.getContainer().style.clip = ''
      this._rightLayer.getPane().style.clip = ''
// end fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
    }
    this._removeEvents()
    L.DomUtil.remove(this._container)

    this._map = null

    return this
  },

  setLeftLayers: function (leftLayers) {
    this._leftLayers = asArray(leftLayers)
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  setRightLayers: function (rightLayers) {
    this._rightLayers = asArray(rightLayers)
    this._updateLayers()
    return this
  },

  _updateClip: function () {
    var map = this._map
    var nw = map.containerPointToLayerPoint([0, 0])
    var se = map.containerPointToLayerPoint(map.getSize())
    var clipX = nw.x + this.getPosition()
    var dividerX = this.getPosition()

    this._divider.style.left = dividerX + 'px'
    this.fire('dividermove', {x: dividerX})
    var clipLeft = 'rect(' + [nw.y, clipX, se.y, nw.x].join('px,') + 'px)'
    var clipRight = 'rect(' + [nw.y, se.x, se.y, clipX].join('px,') + 'px)'
    if (this._leftLayer) {
// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
//      this._leftLayer.getContainer().style.clip = clipLeft
      this._leftLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipLeft
    }
    if (this._rightLayer) {
// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
//      this._rightLayer.getContainer().style.clip = clipRight
      this._rightLayer.getPane().style.clip = clipRight
// end fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
    }
  },

  _updateLayers: function () {
    if (!this._map) {
      return this
    }
    var prevLeft = this._leftLayer
    var prevRight = this._rightLayer
    this._leftLayer = this._rightLayer = null
    this._leftLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
      if (this._map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        this._leftLayer = layer
      }
    }, this)
    this._rightLayers.forEach(function (layer) {
      if (this._map.hasLayer(layer)) {
        this._rightLayer = layer
      }
    }, this)
    if (prevLeft !== this._leftLayer) {
      prevLeft && this.fire('leftlayerremove', {layer: prevLeft})
      this._leftLayer && this.fire('leftlayeradd', {layer: this._leftLayer})
    }
    if (prevRight !== this._rightLayer) {
      prevRight && this.fire('rightlayerremove', {layer: prevRight})
      this._rightLayer && this.fire('rightlayeradd', {layer: this._rightLayer})
    }
    this._updateClip()
  },

  _addEvents: function () {
    var range = this._range
    var map = this._map
    if (!map || !range) return
    map.on('move', this._updateClip, this)
    map.on('layeradd layerremove', this._updateLayers, this)
    on(range, getRangeEvent(range), this._updateClip, this)
// start fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
//    on(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', cancelMapDrag, this)
//    on(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', uncancelMapDrag, this)
    on(range, isTouch() ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', cancelMapDrag, this)
    on(range, isTouch() ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', uncancelMapDrag, this)
// end fix for Leaflet 1.9 -----------------------
  },

  _removeEvents: function () {
    var range = this._range
    var map = this._map
    if (range) {
      off(range, getRangeEvent(range), this._updateClip, this)
      off(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchstart' : 'mousedown', cancelMapDrag, this)
      off(range, L.Browser.touch ? 'touchend' : 'mouseup', uncancelMapDrag, this)
    }
    if (map) {
      map.off('layeradd layerremove', this._updateLayers, this)
      map.off('move', this._updateClip, this)
    }
  }
})

L.control.sideBySide = function (leftLayers, rightLayers, options) {
  return new L.Control.SideBySide(leftLayers, rightLayers, options)
}

module.exports = L.Control.SideBySide

}).call(this,typeof global !== "undefined" ? global : typeof self !== "undefined" ? self : typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : {})
},{"./layout.css":2,"./range.css":4}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
var inject = require('./node_modules/cssify');
var css = ".leaflet-sbs-range {\r\n    position: absolute;\r\n    top: 50%;\r\n    width: 100%;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-divider {\r\n    position: absolute;\r\n    top: 0;\r\n    bottom: 0;\r\n    left: 50%;\r\n    margin-left: -2px;\r\n    width: 4px;\r\n    background-color: #fff;\r\n    pointer-events: none;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n";
inject(css, undefined, '_i6aomd');
module.exports = css;

},{"./node_modules/cssify":3}],3:[function(require,module,exports){
'use strict'

function injectStyleTag (document, fileName, cb) {
  var style = document.getElementById(fileName)

  if (style) {
    cb(style)
  } else {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]

    style = document.createElement('style')
    if (fileName != null) style.id = fileName
    cb(style)
    head.appendChild(style)
  }

  return style
}

module.exports = function (css, customDocument, fileName) {
  var doc = customDocument || document
  /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
  if (doc.createStyleSheet) {
    var sheet = doc.createStyleSheet()
    sheet.cssText = css
    return sheet.ownerNode
  } else {
    return injectStyleTag(doc, fileName, function (style) {
      /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
      if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = css
      } else {
        style.innerHTML = css
      }
    })
  }
}

module.exports.byUrl = function (url) {
  /* istanbul ignore if: not supported by Electron */
  if (document.createStyleSheet) {
    return document.createStyleSheet(url).ownerNode
  } else {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    var link = document.createElement('link')

    link.rel = 'stylesheet'
    link.href = url

    head.appendChild(link)
    return link
  }
}

},{}],4:[function(require,module,exports){
var inject = require('./node_modules/cssify');
var css = ".leaflet-sbs-range {\r\n    -webkit-appearance: none;\r\n    display: inline-block!important;\r\n    vertical-align: middle;\r\n    height: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    border: 0;\r\n    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);\r\n    min-width: 100px;\r\n    cursor: pointer;\r\n    pointer-events: none;\r\n    z-index: 999;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-fill-upper {\r\n    background: transparent;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-fill-lower {\r\n    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);\r\n}\r\n/* Browser thingies */\r\n\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-range-track {\r\n    opacity: 0;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-track {\r\n    opacity: 0;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-tooltip {\r\n    display: none;\r\n}\r\n/* For whatever reason, these need to be defined\r\n * on their own so dont group them */\r\n\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-webkit-slider-thumb {\r\n    -webkit-appearance: none;\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-ms-thumb {\r\n    margin: 0;\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-range-thumb {\r\n    padding: 0;\r\n    right: 0    ;\r\n    background: #fff;\r\n    height: 40px;\r\n    width: 40px;\r\n    border-radius: 20px;\r\n    cursor: ew-resize;\r\n    pointer-events: auto;\r\n    border: 1px solid #ddd;\r\n    background-image: url(\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAFAAAABQCAMAAAC5zwKfAAAABlBMVEV9fX3///+Kct39AAAAAnRSTlP/AOW3MEoAAAA9SURBVFjD7dehDQAwDANBZ/+l2wmKoiqR7pHRcaeaCxAIBAL/g7k9JxAIBAKBQCAQCAQC14H+MhAIBE4CD3fOFvGVBzhZAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC\");\r\n    background-position: 50% 50%;\r\n    background-repeat: no-repeat;\r\n    background-size: 40px 40px;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-moz-range-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-ms-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled::-webkit-slider-thumb {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:disabled {\r\n    cursor: default;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range:focus {\r\n    outline: none!important;\r\n}\r\n.leaflet-sbs-range::-moz-focus-outer {\r\n    border: 0;\r\n}\r\n\r\n";
inject(css, undefined, '_1tlt668');
module.exports = css;

},{"./node_modules/cssify":3}]},{},[1]);

